# Using RFID Reader on Node JS

Tags: node.js, rfid

I'm working for a public library in my town, and I have developed a web application to handle the borrowing process and other administration problem. A few years ago, the library bought and attached the books in the library with a RFID tag, and with it, also bought a RFID Reader to be used in the borrowing process, and a RFID Sensor Security Gate, to prevent the books from being taken out without proper administration process. For the RFID Reader to be used, the vendor gave me a JAVA applet to connect the RFID Reader to my web application, as it's not possible to access a device from  the web with just Javascript or JQuery.

Currently, the library is asking me to develop a **kiosk application** for the library's self service center. I currently developing the kiosk application with **Node JS**, and I managed to create the user and password authentication with native Javascript and AJAX function.

[image]
[image: User ID authentication]
[image: Password authentication]
[image]
[image]
[image]

However, problem occured when I tried to use the RFID Reader to detect the books. I tried using some modules called **node-hid**, but everytime I run the application, it gave me an error message.

[image]

I used:

- Windows 10
- Node v10.16.3
- npm v6.9.2
- Electron v5.0.6

Some poeple in the forums recommended to rebuild and reinstall the module and the node, but it's not working for me. Others told me to downgraded the Node or the npm using nvm, but from what i read, nvm only worked for Linux. Honestly, I'm still new in Node JS, and I'm a little bit confused: regarding the error message above, which one is actually the problem? The Node version, or the npm version?

Struggling, I tried to forget about using modules about RFID, and start from the scratch by detecting devices connected on USB first, so I use **serialport** module, but the same error persist.

I expected to be able to read the books' ID from the RFID tag, and rewrite some blocks in it to prevent the alarms from the RFID Sensor Security Gate goes off.

Any supports regarding the error above, or a recommendations to use another module will be appreciated. I'm at the end of my rope here.

Comment: Can you paste in package.json

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit late but I'm putting it here just in case someone passed by it.

You are getting this error because you are using a native module which is ok for node, but because electron is a modified node, so in order for thhat to work: you need to rebuild for electron instead:

- Add the electron-rebuild package
  `npm i -D electron-rebuild`
- Remove the node-modules folder, as well as the packages-lock.json file.
- Run `npm install` to install all modules.
- Run `./node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild` or `.\node_modules\.bin\electron-rebuild.cmd` for Windows to rebuild everything.